# Generate temp folder in project structure

Tags: go

I’ve a Go program which user should get it via `go get` command.
my program is command line program,
Now my program should generate temp folder  to do some manipulation on data and when it finish generate zip with the artificats on the same folder that the user is running the cmd program,
my question is where its better to **generate the temp folder**?

```
go
-src
—-userapp
```

if the user open terminal in the the user app and run some command I need to create (at the end some zip with artefacts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard temporary directory of the operating system for manipulation. You can get it by calling function [`os.TempDir()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#TempDir). Put the final results in the current directory, you can get it by calling [`os.Getwd()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd).